# MVC EF recursion for categories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, recursion

I want to generate a tree structure of my categories in MVC EF and I don't know how. I found a few things on the Internet but I could not put them together.

My categories table:

```
id
category_name
parent_id
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was how can I find the tree of each base node.

I managed to write a code for this.

```
public Hashtable FindChildCategories(List<Categories> categories, int parentId)
    {
        Hashtable retval = new Hashtable();

        foreach (Categories c in categories)
        {
            if (c.ParentId == parentId)
            {
                retval.Add(c, FindChildCategories(categories, c.Id));
            }
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

This code runs for every base node from my table (a node that doesn't have a `parentId`).

Comment: So, does this answer your own question? Or if this is part of your question, better remove this answer and modify your question to include these.

Comment: This is one possible answer for my question.